# ESS hooks breaking buffers not associated with files

Tags: hooks, ess

This is a weird one, for me: I use both ESS (for R programming) and [gist.el](https://github.com/defunkt/gist.el) for (surprise!) interacting with github gists. Except, now I have a problem: every time I try to view a gist locally, ESS's R hook tries to read the dir of the gist, which is nil, and explodes:

```
Debugger entered--Lisp error: (wrong-type-argument stringp nil)
  directory-file-name(nil)
  ess-r-package--find-package-path()
  ess-r-package--local-package-info()
  ess-r-package-get-info()
  ess-r-package-auto-activate()
  run-hooks(after-change-major-mode-hook)
  run-mode-hooks()
  fundamental-mode()
  normal-mode()
  gist-fetch("3116a156329746b082d9")
  gist-fetch-current()
  funcall-interactively(gist-fetch-current)
  call-interactively(gist-fetch-current nil nil)
  command-execute(gist-fetch-current)
```

So that's pretty cool. Adding to the general sense of bewilderment: this happens on *any* gist, regardless of what major mode it should end up in. (I assume this is some deep ESS black magic trying to determine if it should leap in to action or not.)

So I'm trying to figure out:

1. Is this a bug in ESS? Sure seems like a bug, but I don't actually grok the core behavior of ESS in this instance, so I'm not sure.
2. Whether it's a bug or not, any suggestions on a work-around?

Comment: This is a bug in ESS, but I am pretty sure it was fixed months ago. Please check the issue tracker.

Comment: Oh interesting -- I'm running the very latest ESS, but perhaps I need to re-install?

Comment: Ah, alas -- a fresh re-install off ESS doesn't actually fix this. @VitoshKa, I can't find anything on the issue tracker; I don't want to bother y'all with duplicate issues, but I'm happy to open one unless you know where the old issue is?